# JProfiler: Unable to get the agent to run on the Netweaver server for remote profiling

Tags: jprofiler, netweaver

We are trying to remotely profile our application running on a Netweaver server. The box is Windows Server 2008 running in AWS. We have opened port 8849 and we had it working for a few minutes about 2 weeks ago. Now, the agent seems to have unloaded itself, and no amount of coaxing can get it to load again. Our agent path is set via the Netweaver config tool in the system settings as follows:

-agentpath:D:\jprofiler\jprofiler9\bin\windows-x64\jprofilerti.dll=port=8849

The following jvm settings are set on the server. We're experimenting with some of them to see if there is a conflict there:

- -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
- -XX:+DumpDetailedClassStatisticOnOutOfMemory
- -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
- -XX:+PrintGCDetails
- -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
- -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
- -XX:-StringInternTableInPermGen
- -XX:-TraceClassUnloading
- -XX:HeapDumpPath=OOM.hprof
- -XX:MaxErrorQueueLength=200
- -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=1
- -XX:SurvivorRatio=6
- -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=90
- -Xss2m
- -javaagent:D:\PQM3\newrelic\newrelic.jar

Are there any debug parameters we can add to the agentPath that may help us further detect what's going on?

jpenable did not work for us, so we had to add the agent manally.

Comment: There should be output prefixed with JProfiler> in stderr when you start the process with the -agentpath parameter. Can you add that to the question?

Comment: The stderr is empty after we start the process.

Comment: This would mean the the -agentpath parameter is not passed to the profiled JVM. If it is there will be output on stderr, either by the JVM that the agent could not be loaded or by the JProfler agent, prefixed with "JProfiler>"

Comment: We finally got it to work. The problem was, we were unable to add the agentPath via the config tool to the additional parameters tab. We were adding it to the system tab, which, apparently was the wrong place. The conflict was with our agent parameter to newrelic. Once we disabled it, we were allowed to add the jprofiler agent path to the additional parameters tab and everything started working. Thanks for your help!